# How do I remotely exclude subdirectories with rsync?

Tags: rsync

I want to copy `/opt/intranet` and all its subdirectories and files but i need to exclude `/opt/intranet/helpdesk` and all of its children.  Do I start from the server I want to copy, or do I run the command from the destination server and ssh the command to the source?

`rsync -avr -e ssh root@10.18.30.1:/opt/intranet --exclude=/opt/intranet/helpdesk .`  failed as it was syncing the helpdesk folder.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `--exclude=root@10.18.30.1:/opt/intranet/helpdesk`? Just guessing.

Comment: No, it still syncs it.

Comment: Yeah, I've just tried it. It turns out that `--exclude` paths have to be relative to the source path. In your case it probably should look like this `--exclude=helpdesk`. Take a look here: http://serverfault.com/questions/396117/rsync-from-remote-to-local-excluding-folders

Comment: Yeah that did the trick, the `--exclude=helpdesk` without the IP address a second time.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify, into the `--exclude` option, a:

> Path **relative** to the `source path` of the `rsync` command

In **your** case:

```
rsync -avr -e ssh root@10.18.30.1:/opt/intranet . --exclude=helpdesk
```

In **general** case:

```
rsync -avr -e ssh root@$HOSTNAME:/<source_folder> . --exclude=<relative folder>
```